# wedge product (exterior algebra)

Tags: multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I got confused on the operator of the wedge product on other 2 vectors. Please help.

Let $V=\mathbb R^3,e_1= (1,0,0),e_2= (0,1,0)$, and $e_3= (0,0,1)$.  Find:
$3e_1∧4e_3((1,α,0),(0,β,1))$, where α,β are irrational numbers.

Comment: This looks like an exercise so you must have some lecture notes. Where in your lecture notes is it mentioned that the wedge product of two vectors can be seen as a map?

Comment: this notation indeed seems kind of off. Indeed one can define the exterior algebra over a universal property involving maps, but this does not make the wedge into functions, but as a universal space for alternating functions to facto over.
Especially since there are 4 vectors appearing, but only 1 wedge

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842911/how-to-perform-wedge-product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the notation correctly,
$$
(3e_1 \wedge 4e_3)((1,\alpha,0), (0,\beta,1)) 
= 12 (e_1 \wedge e_3)((1,\alpha,0), (0,\beta,1)) \\
= 12 (e_1 \otimes e_3)((1,\alpha,0), (0,\beta,1)) 
- 12 (e_1 \otimes e_3)((0,\beta,1), (1,\alpha,0)) \\
= 12\ e_1(1,\alpha,0)\ e_3(0,\beta,1) 
- 12\ e_1(0,\beta,1)\ e_3(1,\alpha,0) \\
= 12 ((1,0,0)\cdot(1,\alpha,0)) ((0,0,1)\cdot(0,\beta,1)) 
- 12 ((1,0,0)\cdot(0,\beta,1)) ((0,0,1)\cdot(1,\alpha,0)) \\
= 12 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 - 12 \cdot 0 \cdot 0
= 12
$$

Comment: I think you forget the fraction $\frac{1}{2!}$

Comment: I was unsure if there should be such a factor.