# How to compute the Wedge product in $\bigwedge ^3$ as well as $\bigwedge ^2$

Tags: exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

I want to know on how to compute the Wedge Product, since this is the first time I am doing it. I wanted to compute:

$$e_1 \wedge(e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge (-2 e_1 +e_4) $$

Though currently I have no idea how to do it, so I tried my calculation onto the inner term:

$$(e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge (-2 e_1 +e4)$$

from which I got:

$$-2e_2 \wedge e_1 + e_2\wedge e_4 + e_4\wedge e_1 $$

and the term $ e_4\wedge e_4$ disappears due to the wedge with itself is zero due to the alternating property.

I just want a runthrough on how to do this really, on how to shorten terms as well for continuous computation.

Comment: Oh yes it's a typo i can edit this.

Comment: Just continue doing so.

Comment: Alright should be fixed now. Though is my current computation correct ?

Comment: Where has the initial $e_1$ gone?

Comment: As said above, i was currently just computing the term $(e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge (-2 e_1 +e4)$ for now, just so i know if i understood it. I will continue with the initial $e_1$ later.

Comment: Your computation is correct (usually, one writes $-e_1\wedge e_2$ rather than $e_2\wedge e_1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Glad to know this. I will continue with my computation on my own then. Just wanted to know.

Comment: Then, $e_1 \wedge (e_2 \wedge e_1)$ vanishes since you have $e_1$ twice.

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2842962/332594

Answer (score 1):

I'd reorder the wedges to evaluate, moving the $e_1$ wedge to the end (this flips the sign twice):

$$\begin{aligned}e_1 \wedge(e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge (-2 e_1 +e_4)  &=(-1)^2 (e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge (-2 e_1 +e_4)  \wedge e_1 \\ &=       (e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge \left( { (-2 e_1 +e_4)  \wedge e_1 } \right) \\ &=       (e_2 - \frac{1}{2}e_4) \wedge \left( { e_4 \wedge e_1 } \right) \\ &=       e_2 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_1.\end{aligned}$$

The term with $e_4$ wedged with itself can be dropped because $e_4 \wedge e_4 \wedge e_1 = (e_4 \wedge e_4) \wedge e_1 = 0 \wedge e_1 = 0.$